# Choosing between "error", "inconsistency", "discrepancy"

Tags: word-usage

**Context:**
I generate a report for an ID and fix errors in it. Then I share it with another person who verifies with his own data if all the errors are fixed or not, if not point out some more errors, and then I have to make changes to the report generation process. So I made some changes and now I want to ask the other person apart from the last error you pointed out do you see any other error too?
I want to put it differently, so I thought of following:

> Besides this difference, do you notice any other inconsistencies in the report?

Not sure if it conveys the meaning properly, or "*discrepancies*" will be a more appropriate word, or any other suggestion?

Comment: Purely a personal perspective, but I'm inclined to see ***inconsistencies*** in such contexts as referring to elements within the report which ***conflict with other elements in the report***, whereas ***discrepancies*** is more likely to refer to elements which ***conflict with known real-world facts.***

Comment: Have you looked up the differences among those words in a dictionary? Which do you think is best? Why are you unsure about the others?

Comment: Another way is to ask if your report **jibes** with his data.

Comment: *Discrepancy* is a polite word for *error*. If you tell someone "There is an error in your work" that means "You are wrong"; if you say "There is a discrepancy in your work" that allows room for the error having another source and the person being blameless. Similarly you may want to say that faults in your work are "discrepancies" not "errors" if you don't want to look bad.

Answer (score 2):

Inconsistencies and discrepancies are, in general, different from errors. As near as I can tell from your description of your context, neither *inconsistencies* nor *discrepancies* could be substituted for *errors* without changing your meaning.

Why not continue using *errors*? There’s a useful rule of thumb that as long as your meaning is the same, your word choice should remain the same. This prevents causing readers to puzzle, “Why is a different term used here? Is there some different meaning intended? Hmmm…”

On the other hand, your proposed sentence begins, “Besides this **difference**.” So maybe you’re not dealing with errors at all? In that case, it would be *inconsistencies* and *discrepancies* that better convey your intended meaning.